# Can multimap_intersection and multimap_difference be implemented similar to set_intersection and set_difference ,?

Tags: c++

Can we implement multimap_intersection or multimap_difference function as we do for  set_intersection and set_difference in STL?

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or are you actually trying to implement something like this? Or are you looking for an existing implementation?

Comment: @Mat i saw implementation in set and have implemented it but i saw set had inbuilt functions for that but not in case of multimap . So do we need to write it with our own logic or is there something existing of such kind ?

Comment: It depends on the semantics that you want to provide. Given sets { A, A, A, B, C, D } and { A, A, B, B, C, E }, what would the output of your operations be?

Comment: @David sets only allows one unique Value so we cant have set as you said above but in case of Map since we have key and value we can have multiple value for same key ..So i just wanted to know if its possible or not or someone who has ever implemented or used similar thing in multimap or map ?

Comment: In my previous comment, try to read `set` as `multiset`. Multisets allow for multiple instances of a key in the same way that multimaps do, and the question is still the same, what would be your expected outcome for the operations on two multisets as the above?

Comment: Since maps are basically sets of `pair<Key, Value>` with a comparison which compares only the key parts, implementing intersection/difference for these is more or less the same as implementing these operations for sets. as David Rodríguez - dribeas showed you'd have to define how these operations should work for multiset/multimap before one can speculate about implementation (personally I think it's kind of pointless to bother, since those operations don't really make sense for multi* containers)

Comment: @David say i have two multiset first one with { "1-2 Sameer", "2-1 dilip", "3-4 kiran"} where " 1-2" , "2-1" etc are key and "Sameer" and dilip are values  and similarly i have 1 more multimap { "1-2 Sameer", "2-1 Ram", "3-4 kiran"} then the intersection of both the multimap should fetch me  iterator for multimap { "1-2 Sameer",  "3-4 kiran"}

Comment: To be clear, given a key value pairs as `<K,V>`, your first multimap would be `{ <1,S>, <2,D>, <3,K> }` and the second one `{ <1,S>, <2,R>, <3,K> }`, right? If that is the case, then you will have to provide your own implementation as you are not only comparing the keys, but rather the key-value pair as if it were a composed key. I would suggest that you create a `set< pair<const string,string>, my_comparer >` where each stored pair is the `value_type` of your multiset and `my_comparer` is a functor that compares keys and then values. Sidenote: I am not sure that you fully understand multimaps

Comment: @David Thanks for your suggestion David. I am working on maps recently and certainly not an expert on it, I knew that in maps we do have key ,mapped to values and in set since we have just value  we can easily compare  it to get intersection and difference . anyways thanks for letting me know about the my_comparer thing . I will try and use the same functor and let you know in case of any issues . Happy New Year and Regards

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite vague, and the comments clarify some but not all the problem. The most simplistic answer is that you can implement (given a proper definition) almost anything, and as such you can implement your version of a difference or intersection for multimaps. If the question is whether the `set_difference` can be used directly for your purpose, the answer is no.

The problem is that `set_intersection` and `set_difference` are implemented based on the assumption that the iterator ranges are *sorted*, which is true for the *keys* in an ordered associative container (`set`, `map`, `multiset`, `multimap`) but not for the combination of (key,value) which seems to be what you want to obtain the difference of.

A workaround would be creating a functor that compares pairs of the key-value types, and using that as an ordering for a `set` (not `multiset`). Then you can insert the values in your multimaps to the sets and operate on them. Finally reverse the operation by creating new multimaps from the intersecting/difference set.

Comment: I guess that suggestion of implementing it first in set and mltimap would work ..but that may unneccessary increment my LOC and also i will have to create first populate set with my values and then multimap and that might increase time complexity ... Newaz thanks again for your prompt reply